# How to establish HTTPS/ssl/tls Backend <=> Frontend connection using angular 13?

Tags: asp.net, angular, ssl, webapi

I have a API-REST service in ASP.NET CORE web-api NET 6. I am using client certificate authentication with the following configuration.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.ServerCertificate = serverCertificate;
                    listenOptions.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
                    listenOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                    listenOptions.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
                    //listenOptions.AllowAnyClientCertificate();
                    listenOptions.ClientCertificateValidation = (certificate, chain, errors) =>
                    {
                        if (chain.Build(certificate))
                    //Add certificate verification
                            return true;
                        return false;
                    };
                });
                options.ListenLocalhost(7120, op =>
                {
                    op.UseHttps(serverCertificate);
                    op.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                    op.UseConnectionLogging();
                });
            });
```

It works perfectly from POSTMAN adding the client certificate issued by my CA and its intermediate certificate.

[image: testing service in postman]

I get this error in Angular. (ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT)

I have the CORS already configured.

How can I send the client's certificate from Angular to the backend or how do I establish communication?

Comment: Angular does not interfere in the mutual TLS process. Your end users must install the client certificate(s) on their machine so that their web browsers can pick it up and perform authentication. If that's not what you really want, you might not use mutual TLS at all. In `ClientCertificateValidation` handler, please write the failed certificate details to logging so that you can verify if the browsers present correct certificate(s).

Answer (score 0):

there is no need that your frontend app (spa) knows any thing about tls or domain or IP your server has

you have environment variable

```js
//development
baseUrl:'localhost:5001'
//production
// enviroment.prod.ts
baseUrl:'/api/'
```

when your in production build for it

simply do not use certificate for developement